# React Native: What is the role of ports?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, networking, websocket, port

In a React Native app, I know that port 8081 is used, and Websockets are used. What I don't understand is which two entities are connecting to each other via port 8081 or via websockets? If I'm running an app on an emulator on the same device I'm writing the code on, what entity makes a request to which other entity on port 8081? I thought that using ports was only for connecting between different devices. Is the client the emulator and the server the Metro bundler?

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you are facing any issues with port duplications you can change the running port of react-native by using this command then you will know which port is running your react native code

```
react-native start --port 9988
```

in the above code, the new running port will be 9988

Comment: Hi Saqid, that's useful to know, but unfortunately doesn't address anything in the original question.

Comment: can you explain more what exactly issue you are facing that I can update my answer in proper manners